# Command to move a text file (contains list of files) to an archive folder

Tags: command-line, command

I want to move all the files listed in a text document (logs.txt) to a archive folder. I tried with the below mentioned command but I was unable to move  the listed files to the archive folder.

Command: 
 move C:\Users\krishna\Desktop\Backup\logs.txt C:\Users\krishna\Desktop\Backup\Archive

Note: I am able to move only text file but not the files listed in the txt file

Can anyone please help me in fixing this?

  -

Comment: Looks like you're in a windows environment. Is this correct?

Comment: yes ! I am using windows environment

Comment: I've provided an answer below. I'm not sure how your log file is set up but if it is set up one file per line, try that code. Full Disclosure: I did not test it as I'm on a mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each filename is on its own line (if this is not the case please update me on the format of the logs.txt), you'll need to loop through each line and use that text to move the desired file. The following is something I came up with after some quick research. I'm not a windows guy myself but you can give it a shot and see if that works for you.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %A in (C:\Users\krishna\Desktop\Backup\logs.txt ) do (
  move %A C:\Users\krishna\Desktop\Backup\Archive
)
```

Comment: Hello Cory Kleiser !! It is saying that %%A is not expected at this time !!

Comment: Give %A  a try instead

Comment: Glad I could help.. Happy coding :)